# Error 404 while adding dialog plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I tried to add a cordova plugin using this command:

```
cordova plugin add "org.apache.cordova.dialogs"
```

But this aint working and I'm getting an error saying:

> Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Answer (score 6):

Try running `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs` as described in the [documentation of the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs#installation).

If this doesn't work you can try to call the add method directly with the GitHub link like so:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/`

Sometimes `npm cache clean` magically solves problems like this.

If all of the above doesn't work npm might just be down. In this case check out the [npmbot on twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/npmjs) and just try again later.

Comment: I did as you said  but again an error shows up saying: Error:Current working directory isnot a cordova based project

Comment: Then switch to your project directory first. Use the `cd` command.

Comment: The same error still persisting . Could you provide with another solution

Comment: This error still persisting inspite of doing what you have said

Comment: It might be to late but I added some more ideas to deal with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `org.apache.cordova.*` to `cordova-plugin-*`

So, your new command would be,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Answer (score 0):

The "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" plugin is the old version. The newer versions have the name "cordova-plugin-dialogs".

Answer (score 0):

this should work : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs

Comment: please consider adding more details about the answer